# Unable to change text font in javascript for adobe acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I am creating this pdf form and i want to change the textFont for one of my field.

```
var one = this.getField("one");
one.textColor = ["RGB",0,0,0];
var two = this.getField("two");

//this function that checks if the destination field is blank and if so popluates it
if(two.value==''||two.value==null)
{
two.value=one.value;
two.textColor = ["RGB",0.5,0.5,1];
two.textFont = "Brush Script";
}
```

The error i am getting is

```
InvalidSetError: Set not possible, invalid or unknown.
Field.textFont:10:AcroForm:one:Annot1:OnBlur:Action1
```

I am not sure that i am using the right name for the textfont or not.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I can change the font to any other installed font, **except** those **with spaces** in the name, even _Comic Sans MS_ fails :-(